# Jacobians and Manipulator Dynamics

Tags: mechanical-engineering, electrical-engineering, control-engineering, aerospace-engineering, robotics

[image: This is the Question that needs to be modelled]
This is a Stanford Manipulator
I started off working on it by initially

1. setting up the DH table
2. Transformation Matrix and then Homogeneous Transformation Matrix
3. I started finding the linear and angular velocity for each link but the issue is that while calculating the linear velocity as the matrix are both 3x1 that need to be cross multiplied...
   v + w(omega) x P
   Im getting this wrong
4. I'm confused as to how to get the {0} , i think I should multiply the Jacobian that needs to be found by a Rotation 3 w.r.t 0 ?
5. The singularities, by taking the determinant and then setting it to 0

**I also need to derive the Equations of Dynamics, can anyone list the steps?**
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]